# Integral domain of order 4

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that there is no integral domain of order 4.

Note: Trying with a contradiction.But without any results!

Comment: What exactly were you asked to prove? I can think of an integral domain of order $4$...

Comment: Two excellent answers have been posted on this. However, I encourage you to take this problem one step further. See if you can't prove that every finite integral domain is a field - and hence, every finite integral domain has prime power order. Since there is a field of every prime power order, that really classifies a lot!

Answer (score 13):

That's because the statement is false; there ***is*** an integral domain of order $4$, namely
$$(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x^2+x+1).$$
This is the only one (up to isomorphism). More generally, for a natural number $n$, there is an integral domain with $n$ elements if and only if $n$ is a prime power. [This is discussed in an older answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/43797/264).

Comment: Our lecturer helped us in solving that " There is no integral domain of order 6"! And he gave this as a homework!

Answer (score 11):

The answers by Zev and T. Bongers are excellent but let me note:

***Exercise 1***: Prove that a finite integral domain is a field.

***Exercise 2***: Prove that every finite field has prime power order.

***Exercise 3***: Prove that there is a field of every possible prime power order. (Zev has linked to another one of his excellent answers; have a look.)

So, if you give me a number and can tell me whether or not it's a prime power, then I can tell you whether or not there's an integral domain of that order!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

There is an integral domain (in fact a field) of order $4$; namely, the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$.

Comment: Haha, three comments expressing the same idea within the same minute. Awesome. +1 :)